# Parsing PDF file with irregular table to dataframe - python

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, pdf

I'm tring to parse a PDF file with text images and tables to dataframe.The problem is with irregular table. Is it even possible?[table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXMuF.png)

I'm using **tabula.io import read_pdf** for regular tables:

```
df_list = read_pdf(r'C:\pdf_files\pdf-test.pdf', multiple_tables=True, pages="1,2")
```

It's not perfect but it works.

For now, my "best" option for the complex tables is to read the file to a list of words and then parse it by locations -> f`ile = pdf.PdfReader(file_name)` but I want to believe that Python got a more elegant way to handle this.